# set height of dateInput() field in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a lot of generated input fields on an shiny app and I want to make it more dense by lowering the height of the `dateinput` fields. However, the height tag only shrinks the box and make it overflow into the next input. So, how do I shrink the `dateInput()` fields so it is only a little higher than the text?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$style(".shiny-date-input  {height : 30px;}")
  ,dateInput("date1","date1")
  ,dateInput("date2","date2")
  ,textInput("text","text")
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output, session){})
```

[image]

**Update:** To clearify, I want the `dateInput` (and possibly the `textinput` also) frame to be less tall without it extending into the blow input:
[image]

Comment: Do you need some special style? You used `tags$style(".shiny-date-input  {height : 30px;}")`.

Comment: I just want the "frame" of the `dateinput()` to be less tall. I tried with height in the css style, but that only made the div less tall and the "frame" then extends into the below input. I don't what that but a shorter input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in `.form_control` :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$style(".shiny-input-container  {line-height: 5px; height : 25px}")
  ,tags$style(".form-control  {height: 25px;}")

  ,dateInput("date1","date1")
  ,dateInput("date2","date2")
  ,textInput("text","text")
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output, session){})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class `input-sm` to the widgets in order to make them a bit smaller. To do so, use `shinyjs`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  dateInput("date1","date1"),
  br(),
  dateInput("date2","date2"),
  br(),
  textInput("text","text")
)

shinyApp(ui, 
         function(input, output, session){
           addClass("date1", "input-sm")
           addClass("date2", "input-sm")
           addClass("text", "input-sm")
         }
)
```

Comment: That does make it a little smaller, but there is still plenty of leg room there to srink even more. Thanks.

Comment: @FacyMacFacyFace Maybe you can try the [airDatepicker](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.3/topics/airDatepicker). It allows to select multiple dates and there is an 'inline' option.

Comment: really nice date picker. Especially with time. I even had the package already, but it does not really solve this issue.